# Comparing Text boxes to be used in filtering data table c#

Tags: string, datagridview, datatable, comparison, rowfilter

I want to compare two textboxes with data in a datatable and use this comparison operation to filter the datetable.
For example: I want to show all data (rows and columns) that have value x in which:

```
textbox1.text>x>textbox1.text
```

I have used "`Like`" operator inside string format to get the value that matches the value in the text-box completely but I could not do the required range filtering operation

Here is my code related to the specified question:

```
 dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Type Like '%{0}%' and Gain Like" +
            "'%{1}%'" +
            "and Year Like'%{2}%' and MotorPower Like '%{3}%'" +
            "and Profit Like '%{4}%'", textBoxType .Text,textBoxGain.Text
            , textBoxYear.Text, textBoxBiggerthan.Text, textBoxKar.Text);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

I have another input textbox called `textBoxSmallerthan.Text`
and I want to make my range for MotorPower column in datatable (datagridview) between `textBoxBiggerthan.Text` and  `textBoxSmallerthan.Text`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) shows the numbers do not need be wrapped with single quote makers. So the format is:

`Columnname < Number`

So the final filter should be something like this:

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Type Like '%{0}%' and Gain Like" +
            "'%{1}%'" +
            "and Year Like'%{2}%' and MotorPower > {3} and MotorPower < {4}" +
            "and Profit Like '%{4}%'", textBoxType .Text,textBoxGain.Text
            , textBoxYear.Text, textBoxSmallerthan.Text, textBoxBiggerthan.Text, textBoxKar.Text);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: Sorry, but that code did not work. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: You will need to format string to a valid Datetime. The example in the link is in the m/d/y format

Comment: I tried to convert range components to datetime but the same error message has shown up.

Comment: In addition I think it's not appropriate to use datetime-type data to compare between integer numbers such as for motor power, any other suggestion please?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question I thought you were checking between two dates. Not sure why i thought that . I will update my answer

Comment: In this case the programs will filter the table ONLY  when  an input is given to text boxes of biggest and smallest motor power by the user. Otherwise, there is no data obtained! Why?  I wanted it to be fit with each input case.

Comment: So if there is no input given the filter essential remove everything? Can you not set the filter to default values? Or build the rowfilter depending on what inputs are given by the user.